# Laravel API, how to accept DELETE method

Tags: laravel, api, http-delete

I need to use my API to delete some entities, I create my controller, my methods, the routes. They works fine, all the get and put/patch method works, but with the delete one I have and error throw by my Angular app who consume this api, here is the error :

```
DELETE (Method Not Allowed)
```

In my api route file I set this :

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:  Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization, X-HTTP-Method-Override');
```

Anyone know why it's not working ?

Edit:

Here is my routes (and yes the methods are in the good controller) :

[image]

Comment: Do you have route for delete method?

Comment: I've created my routes with the Route::resource method, and yes I have a route for the delete method (I can see the routes with php:artisan route:list)

Comment: Are you sure, you are issuing the request against the correct `URI`?

Comment: Yes i'm sure, I can see the url requested and it's the good one, the same url with postman works fine. But with angular Laravel throw a MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Answer (score 3):

When you are posting to the Delete url, make sure you have this data in your post request:

```
_method=delete
```

this is just like an input field e.g:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
```

Comment: And how can I add this ? I'm using restangular to do the requests

Comment: I try to add this : `.customDELETE(undefined, undefined, undefined, {_method: 'delete'});` and `.customDELETE(undefined, undefined, undefined, '_method=delete');` but still the same error

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18585010/restangular-post-form-data-in-json-format-in-angular-js

Comment: That's what i'm doing : `this.restangular.one(this.route, resource.uuid).customDELETE(undefined, undefined, undefined, '_method=delete');`

Comment: You need to do something like this: Restangular.all('data.json/:user').post("ul-to-post-to", $scope.data);

Comment: In the documentation it's like this : `Restangular.one("accounts", 123).remove();`, i'm not gonna do a post to make a delete request

Comment: Just try it to see if that's the problem then you can think of another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Method not allowed is an HTTP Status code 405, and it usually translates to the lack of HTTP Verb matching that endpoint

Edit: Also, check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)

e.g.

All of these SHOULD mean different things and DO different things.
If you make a Request to the last url but the url isn't registered (on your routes files or wherever you place them), then that's the error it returns because it matches the name but not the verb

```
POST   url.com/user

GET    url.com/user

PUT    url.com/user

PATCH  url.com/user

DELETE url.com/user
```

Answer (score 0):

try this package [CORS Middleware for Laravel 5](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)